# How to properly use methods in Java for Magic 8 Ball program

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I have no code to paste since all I have is a template of my methods to be used. Hopefully this isn't too broad because I've looked all over and haven't received the answer I'm needing.

Many have seen or heard of a "Magic 8 Ball" program. A user asks a question, and they receive a random answer in return. I could have written the code easily with one method, but now we've delved into using multiple methods and I'm missing a piece of the puzzle.

The rules of this program: 
1) I have to create at least three methods: the main, an input method, and an output method. 
2) I have to use a switch statement for the random answers.
3) I have to use a while loop (or a do-while) to prompt the user to either ask another question, or quit.

I think my only problem lies in where to place each piece of the code. I'm going to need to call a Scanner. That's no big deal. I know how to do the switch statement. I know how to randomize the output. I'm most likely going to use a boolean for the keep going/quit part. But where do I actually PLACE the scanner? The boolean? In the main? In an input method? What about the processing section for the randomization? Are all my variables declared in the main so they spread throughout?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Well, do you need the `Scanner` in the output method, or only in the input method?  You should declare it where it's needed.  The same applies for all the variables you've mentioned.

Comment: What @DavidWallace said is not the best answer, declaring the Scanner in the input method means you have to create it on each iteration of input, which can be very expensive. Creating it once either in main, or in the constructor as a class level object will be much cheaper. If created at class level it can be used directly in input method, otherwise if it is created in main method it can be passed as an argument to the input method.

Comment: I imported java.util.Scanner above everything, and I only need it twice: 1) to ask what the user's question is, and 2) to ask if they want to play again.

Comment: @tinker That depends on whether he/she intends to call the input method multiple times, or just once.  Sure, if it's going to be multiple times, then it should be declared outside.  But if it's going to be just once, then it's best to declare it inside the method.  It's impossible to tell, when his/her design is still so vague.

Comment: True that! Since they are a beginner, it's better to explain both cases and why a specific approach is better. Together we've probably explained that now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating Scanner once either in main, or in the constructor as a class level object will be much cheaper than creating every time you call the input method. If created at class level it can be used directly in input method, otherwise if it is created in main method it can be passed as an argument to the input method.

Boolean can be in the input method because you are directly comparing the input and you have no more use for it.

When you have an object, especially an expensive one, it is better to create it only once wherever applicable, or create it as few times as possible.

Comment: Ok. That helps. I'll go work on my code and come back with my results. Thanks, as always.

Comment: I'll be so glad when I can start answering questions instead of just asking. Things like this make me feel so .....noob-ish.

Comment: One problem... I discovered that I am not allowed to use class variables yet. :-(

Comment: Then you can declare it in main and pass it as a constructor argument.

Comment: I've never done that before. I pasted my completed code below, but I'm curious what that would look like?

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean pass it as a method argument:
Scanner x = new Scanner(....
input(x);

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my sloppy code, and ignore the case names. They are temporary since I will be renaming them. I tried every scenario after compiling. I asked a question, it answered, and it asked if I wanted to ask another. I asked another, it repeated the prompt. I answered "n", and it said "Thanks for playing. Goodbye", and stopped running. Here is my code. Problem solved.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MagicBall {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int random = 0;
    boolean playAgain = true;

   while (playAgain) {
       askAnother(random);
    }//end while
}//end main


public static void askAnother(int r) {

    System.out.print("Hello! What is your question? ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String question = input.nextLine();

    String yes_or_no;
    String next_question;
    randomAnswer(r);

    boolean playAgain = true;

    while(playAgain) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to ask another question? Y to ask, N to quit.");

        yes_or_no = input.nextLine();

        if (yes_or_no.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("What is your next question?");
            next_question = input.nextLine();
            randomAnswer(r);

        }//end if

        else if (yes_or_no.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        playAgain = false;
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing. Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please enter Y or N.");
            continue;
        }//end else
    }//end while
}//end input method

public static int randomAnswer(int r1) {

    r1 = (int)(Math.random() * 9);

switch(r1) {
    case 0: System.out.println("Yes"); break;
    case 1: System.out.println("Yes1"); break;
    case 2: System.out.println("Yes2"); break;
    case 3: System.out.println("Neutral"); break;
    case 4: System.out.println("Neutral1"); break;
    case 5: System.out.println("Neutral2"); break;
    case 6: System.out.println("No"); break;
    case 7: System.out.println("No1"); break;
    case 8: System.out.println("No2"); break;

}//end switch
return r1;
```

}//end output method

}//end MagicBall class

Comment: I answered my own question above.